# The theme doesn't load css and JS files doesn't load in functions.php

Tags: php, theme-development, themes

I'm just moving a theme from Vercel that done in HTML/CSS/Bootstrap/Nuxt.js to be deployed in WordPress trying to enqueue the css files and js but doesn't load at all the content of `front-page.php` and the `header.php` get displayed but without styling just dummy html and the path seem pretty correct if I open the files of the theme itself in the browser it's rendering normally.

```
    if (!function_exists('setup_robertson_theme')) :
        /**
         * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various
         * WordPress features.
         *
         * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme
         * hook, which runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late
         * for some features, such as indicating support post thumbnails.
         */
        function setup_robertson_theme()
        {
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
            wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    
            /**
             * Make theme available for translation.
             * Translations can be placed in the /languages/ directory.
             */
            load_theme_textdomain('robertson_theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
    
            /**
             * Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to <head>.
    
    
             */
            add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
    
            /**
             * Enable support for post thumbnails and featured images.
             */
            add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    
            /**
             * Add support for two custom navigation menus.
             */
            register_nav_menus(array(
                'primary' => __('Primary Menu', '   robertson_theme'),
                'secondary' => __('Secondary Menu', 'myfirsttheme'),
            ));
    
            /**
             * Enable support for the following post formats:
             * aside, gallery, quote, image, and video
             */
            add_theme_support('post-formats', array('aside', 'gallery', 'quote', 'image', 'video'));
    
    
    
            get_header();
        }
    endif; // setup_robertson_theme
    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'setup_robertson_theme');



function add_theme_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('style2', get_theme_file_uri() . '/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('script1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/_nuxt/default.9609efb5.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('script2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/_nuxt/entry.fe69eefa.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('script3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/_nuxt/nuxt-link.bd1ab28f.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);


    // if (is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments')) {
    //     wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
    // }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `get_header()` in the `after_setup_theme`.

The `get_header()` function should be used only in theme template files, not directly in the `after_setup_theme` hook.

Does the theme work now?

Comment: note that `get_header` shouldn't be used that early, it should only be called from theme template files

Comment: Who was that meant for?

Comment: it was to add context to why using get_header on the after_setup_theme hook doesn't work and suggest a better place to put it. Note that the answer was auto-flagged by internal tooling for being very short, you should edit your answer so it's longer and to avoid back and forth. I upvoted it as it identifies the crux of the problem but it doesn't say where to move `get_header` to to fix the problem

Comment: @tom-j-nowell Thanks, the answer is now longer and also has a more detailed explanation.